# Alternative options to upload files to Microsoft Azure using Asp.net 3.5 (latest Azure Storage libraries not compatible)?

Tags: file-upload, c#-3.0, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I installed Windows Azure Storage SDk from nuget. Added the references to my project.

When I make the following reference in my code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

I get an exception of: the type or namespace 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft (are you missing an assembly reference)'?

researching the issue, I read in this blog that it targets 4.0 framework:
http://www.milosev.com/index.php/93-azure/252-the-type-or-namespace-name-windowsazure-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft-are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference

I want use the Azure storage to upload files, is possible to do it with net 3.5? Any alternatives, my site is hosted on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post you reference is really saying that you cannot target the Client Profile.  Make sure your project target Framework is .NET 3.5 and not .NET 3.5 Client Profile.

It can definitely work in .NET 3.5.  We use Azure storage in a project that targets .NET 3.5.

If that is not the issue, with the latest Azure Storage client, does it include binaries for .NET 3.5?  If not, you may have to download and install and older version.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

Comment: Thank you for clarify this, needed to target 3.5.

Comment: @Chaka can you award the bounty?

Comment: I did it yesterday...did you not get it?

Comment: @Chaka I got it for your other question but not this one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice I needed 2 clicks ;)